# Echo database value and create or update record

Tags: php, mysql

I created a sort of (available / unavailable) for staff to store the start and end times/dates of each working day.

Here are my goals:

1. After their personal id is being scanned, they will see their own picture. 
   Also the database will do the following:
2. Database checks or there is any record for the current date.
   Yes = update stop time and date. 
   No = Create new entry.

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

$queryRegistration = "SELECT id, number, startdate FROM timeRegistration";
$resultRegistration = mysqli_query($conn, $queryRegistration);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultRegistration)) {
    if ($row['number'] == $staffNumber) {
        if ($row['startdate'] == $currentDate) {

            echo $row['number'].' '.$row['id'];
            echo '<div class="boxPersons">My Picture</div>';
        } 
      } 
    }
}
```

Goal 1: Does not work. As it creates more divs. How can I manage it only creates one div?

Goal 2: I want to update or create it with functions like:

```
function newEntryDate() {
     $sql = 'INSERT INTO timeRegistration (id, number, startdate, enddate, starttime, endtime, value) VALUES (NULL, "'. $staffNumber .'", "'. $currentDate .'", "", "'. $currentTime .'", "", "")';
     return $sql;
}
```

Question: How can I make sure this works within my script? I don't know how to start.

Comment: We can't help you by scripting the code, you need to plan out each part of the project, code and research each part of your code, then if you're really stuck with a specific part of your code you can come back to us...this question is just too broad.

Comment: for the first goal: you are retrieving all the records, looping all of them and echoing the div for each of the records. Add a WHERE clause to the query to select that specific user only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this.

if your query is retrieving more than 1 row set a limit in query. 
it is better to not use if statement in while loop.

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

$queryRegistration = "SELECT id, number, startdate FROM timeRegistration where startdate =".$currentDate." AND number=".$staffNumber." limit 1;";
$resultRegistration = mysqli_query($conn, $queryRegistration);
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultRegistration)) {
     echo '<div class="boxPersons">My Picture</div>';
     $i++;
}
if($i>0){
    newEntryDate();
}
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: instead of the mysqli functions you should use the mysqli class.

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani; The only thing is that my function newEntryDate, does not work. It looks like it can't use the include('config.php') which is already been loaded in the beginning. How can I use MySQL connection in a function?

Comment: @nhatimme can you share your all code? may be i can help.